# Turn off "Dropbox almost full" notification

Tags: notification, dropbox, dbus

Dropbox for Linux has the annoying habit to send a desktop notification every few hours telling me that my space is almost full. Is there a way (under Gnome-based Ubuntu 17.10 and newer) to filter out this message, while retaining all other notifications (both from Dropbox and other programs)?

Notifications work using Dbus, if I understand correctly, so I wonder if there is a way to 'intercept' this call to filter it out without having to patch and recompile Gnome.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have DropBox installed, but here's how you can configure Gnome3 desktop notifications per application:

- Open **Settings → Notifications**
- Click the application you want to disable notifications from
- You'll be able to turn off the application's notifications, or configure various other aspects.

[image: Notifications window]

On re-reading your question, I see you want to retain other DropBox notifications - so this isn't the answer you're looking for. I've asked much the same question (but phrased more generically) at [Does Gnome3 have a method to filter desktop notifications?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1087046/does-gnome3-have-a-method-to-filter-desktop-notifications?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: This isn't valid, at least on latest Ubuntu versions (Ubuntu 21.10). The Dropbox app doesn't appear in the list. And it's the official from the Drobpox repository.

Comment: still not the case in ubuntu 23