# Does Gnome3 have a method to filter desktop notifications?

Tags: gnome, notification, notify-osd

Does Gnome3 have a method to *filter* desktop notifications based on notification content? If so, how?

Desktop notifications are useful, and I know that it's possible to [turn them off per-application](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034685/turn-off-dropbox-almost-full-notification).

What I'd like to be able to do is filter notifications based on the notification text (or other notification metadata, [something like this rsyslog question](https://serverfault.com/questions/197321/rsyslog-filters-on-message-contents-and-facility)). I have one application which generally sends useful notifications, and also (in a particular environment) sends a notification each couple of minutes which I'd rather not see.

The notification is a harmless warning but annoying, so filtering the notification would be a reasonable solution if the desktop environment supports this.

Similar requests:

- [Filtering DBUS/notify-send messages](https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?274538-Filtering-DBUS-notify-send-messages)
- [Turn off "Dropbox almost full" notification](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034685/turn-off-dropbox-almost-full-notification)

Comment: Can you give examples of two or three messages you want displayed and two or three messages you don't want displayed?

Comment: I don't recall the original context for this question - perhaps @Klesun has a similar situation in mind, if it was they who placed a bounty on this. I expect I would have turned the notifications off, choosing to miss those I found worthwhile rather than tolerate "spammy" app notifications. I've wracked my brain to try and recall, but I don't have it sorry!

Answer (score 0):

It is not clean but you can try these solutions:

1. [Temporarily filter out notifs: Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/252036/how-can-i-temporarily-filter-out-certain-notification-bubbles-coming-from-specif)
2. [Notif filter: UNIX](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/564341/filter-specific-notifications-in-gnome-3-34-2)